# Allow MSO confitional tags by HTML Purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I have an application where users can upload Email content in the form of HTML code. I'm using HTML Purifier to sanitize the input. The input is shown on the same page as preview. The problem is HTML Purifier is stripping out `mso` tags as well, which are important for emails. How can I whitelist them? I understand `HTML.Allowed` or `HTML.AllowedComments` config will be used somehow but not sure exactly how to go about it.

Example:

```
<div class="u-row-container" style="padding: 0px;background-color: transparent">
  <div class="u-row" style="Margin: 0 auto;min-width: 320px;max-width: 600px;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-word;background-color: #003399;">
    <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color: transparent;">
      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding: 0px;background-color: transparent;" align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:600px;"><tr style="background-color: #003399;"><![endif]-->
      
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="600" style="width: 600px;padding: 0px;border-top: 0px solid transparent;border-left: 0px solid transparent;border-right: 0px solid transparent;border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><![endif]-->
<div class="u-col u-col-100" style="max-width: 320px;min-width: 600px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: top;">
  <div style="width: 100% !important;">
  <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--><div style="padding: 0px;border-top: 0px solid transparent;border-left: 0px solid transparent;border-right: 0px solid transparent;border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;"><!--<![endif]-->
```